# How to create a pykcharts instance by retrieving an existing pykcharts chart at page load?

Tags: pykcharts

How to create a `pykcharts` instance by retrieving a table of existing `pykcharts` the page loads?

I mean, when I load my page I load a saved chart and put it in my div

eg:

```
<div id = "MyChart"> <svg ....> it pykcharts </ svg> </ div>
```

I would like to get an instance of `pykcharts` with this chart to edit it.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, to achieve this, you will have to clear the DOM and reinitialise the chart and call the execute again with the edited configuration passed to the chart. There is no provision to edit the existing chart.